# Installed "singular" and can't start it

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, executable

I downloaded [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/), from the terminal. I simply can't find it now that it's installed! It's not in my installed applications and the command "singular" on the terminal gives nothing. 
How do I start it?

Comment: What OS is that?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, the last version

Comment: How did you download it? What command did you use?

Comment: I did use "sudo apt-get install singular"

Comment: Try `Singular` with upper case S.

Comment: Ok it did something. I think that's it, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Singular` with upper case S.

As you can see in the list of files installed be this package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/singular-ui/filelist), the executable is `/usr/bin/Singular`. The same with [different architectures](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/singular-ui).